# Regex to find the nth comma and remove the comma as well as the value

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

Trying to remove the value after 3rd comma and the comma as well

```
a,b,c,d,e,f 
g,h,i,asj,k,l
```

How do write regex to find the 3 comma and remove ,d and ,asj ? I tried this `/(?=(,[^,]{0,3}\n` but not able to get it working

Comment: Why do you have `\n` in the regexp? That will match a newline, but you don't have a newline there.

Comment: `^([^,]*(?:,[^,]*){2}),[^,]*` > `$1` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/oMC55A/1))

Comment: `{0,3}` means between 0 and 3 matches, not exactly 3 matches.

Comment: You have no matching `)` for your `(`. That's not even a complete regexp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
^([^,]*(?:,[^,]*){2}),[^,]*
```

Replace with `$1` to restore the captured Group 1 value. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oMC55A/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `([^,]*(?:,[^,]*){2})` - Group 1:
- `[^,]*` - zero or more chars other than a comma
- `(?:,[^,]*){2}` - two occurrences of a comma and then zero or more chars other than a comma
- `,` - a comma
- `[^,]*` - zero or more chars other than a comma.

Answer (score 2):

Applying lazy match concept here and getting removed values after 3rd comma or so, please try following regex written and tested with shown samples.

```
^((?:.*?,){3})[^,]*,(.*)$
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/8TESZ1/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above regex.

```
^((?:.*?,){3})  ##Matching from starting of value and creating 1st capturing group which has everything till 3rd comma in it. Using lazy match .*?
                ##to make sure its not a greedy match(in a non-capturing group, to avoid creating 2 groups).
[^,]*,          ##Matching everything till next occurrence of comma including that comma.
(.*)$           ##Creating 2nd capturing group which has everything in it till end of the value.
```